# Erro a concatenar mais que 9 ficheiros em C#

Tags: c#, pdf

### PROBLEMA

Fiz um código para concatenar (*Merge*) ficheiros PDF.

O código funciona na totalidade mas quando são mais que 10 ficheiros, em vez de fazer pela ordem: **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.**

Faz pela ordem: **1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9**

### DÚVIDA

Como é que eu posso contornar este problema e fazer pela ordem certa?

### CÓDIGO

O meu código é o seguinte;:

```
public void MergePDF(string folder, string[] e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] files = e;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(folder, FileMode.Create))
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(842, 842);

            Document pdfDoc = new Document(pageSize);
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader;
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(file);
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle mediabox = reader.GetPageSize(1);

                pdfDoc.SetPageSize(mediabox);
                pdf.AddDocument(reader);
                reader.Dispose();
                pbar.PerformStep();
            }
            pdfDoc.Close();
            pdf.Dispose();
            stream.Dispose();
            succed = 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        succed = 0;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessas soluções e veja se lhe é útil: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808670/combine-two-or-more-pdfs

Comment: @MarlonLeandro Obrigada pelo link, mas no fundo essas soluções são semelhantes ao meu código...

Comment: Ou acha que devo usar um ciclo **for** em vez de um ciclo **foreach** ?

Comment: Utilize o `for` e poste o retorno

Comment: @Focos recebi o erro em `CreationTime`
_string does not contain a definition for CreationTime_

Comment: Sim, ja removi o comentário, `CreationTime` só funcionaria se fosse `FileSystemInfo[]`, no seu caso é `string[]`.

Comment: @Focos certo, obrigada na mesma.

Comment: Não entendi... o seu erro uma exception na execução do código ou simplesmente no respeito da ordem dos arquivos?

Comment: Teste desta outra forma: 
`var files = e.OrderBy(f => new string(f.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray()))
            .ThenBy(f =>
            {
                int number;
                if (int.TryParse(new string(f.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()), out number))
                    return number;
                return -1;
            }).ToList();`
No lugar do `string[] files = e;`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo é um erro em respeito à ordem dos arquivos, não é um erro de exception.

Comment: É isso mesmo @Focos ! Obrigada. Podia publicar como resposta e explicar o código por favor? É fácil copiar e colar mas é difícil compreender o que estamos a usar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Resposta

Altere a linha:

```
string[] files = e;
```

por:

```
var files = e
            .OrderBy(f => new string(f.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray()))
            .ThenBy(f => 
                    { int number; 
                      if (int.TryParse(new string(f.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()), out number)) 
                          return number; 
                      return -1; 
                    }
                   ).ToList();
```

### Explicação

O código é bem simples de entender.

Primeiramente o `array` de `string` (variável **e**) é ordenado por **letras** através do método `.OrderBy()`, ao qual é passado como parâmetro um `array` das letras da `string`.

Após a ordenação por letras é realizado a ordenação por **números** através do método `.ThenBy()`, ao qual é verificado se é possível converter o dígito para `int`, caso seja, será retornado o número para ser ordenado.

### Problema

Caso o nome dos arquivos tenham **números no começo** ou **números entre letras**, pode não ordenar corretamente.

Por exemplo, o seguinte conjunto:

```
"1c4",
"c20",
"c3",
"c5a"
```

Resulta em:

```
"c3",
"1c4", //Número no começo
"c20",
"c5a" //Número entre letras
```

### Referência

> [Array.Sort for strings with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796637/10508872)