# Problema com LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Estou a fazer um conversão de PDF para TIFF e converto página a página para uma pasta temporária e no fim vou buscar esses ficheiros para os juntar como no ficheiro original.
O meu código é o seguinte: (utilizei o que está na resposta da minha [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379121/103644)):

```
string pastapdf = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "temporario\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e[i]);
Directory.CreateDirectory(pastapdf);
string pdfFile = Path.Combine(pastapdf, e[i]);
for (int h = 0; h <= (pdfReader.NumberOfPages - 1); h++)
{
    using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(pdfFile))
    {
         var image = document.Render(h, dpi, dpi, true);
         image.Save(pastapdf + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e[i]) + "_" + h.ToString() + ".tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);
         image.Dispose();
    }
}
string save = output + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e[i]) + ".tif";
string[] tifffiles = GetFiles(pastapdf, "*.tif");
var finalfiles = tifffiles.OrderBy(f => 
    new string(f.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray())).ThenBy(f => { 
    int number; if (int.TryParse(new string(f.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()), out number)) 
    return number; return -1; } ).ToList(); //código LINQ para ordenar

JoinTiffLZW(finalfiles.ToArray(), save);
Invoke(new Action(() => { pbar.PerformStep(); pdfReader.Dispose(); }));
```

Deveria fazer: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11....
E está a fazer: 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9....

A minha questão é se alguém me consegue dizer-me outra forma de ordenar a lista ou o que está errado com o meu código?

### TESTE

Carreguei um PDF com 40 páginas. Dividi e converti todas, de seguida fui buscar os ficheiros:
[image: parte 1 do exemplo]

E depois devia ordenar com LINQ, mas o resultado é o seguinte:
[image: parte 2 do exemplo]

E devia estar pela ordem correta, assim quando vou juntar todos, fica a ordem errada.

Comment: Primeira coisa: A atualização do VS em si não pode ter causado isto, só se você instalou junto alguma framework e/ou algo relacionado, porém isso não deveria mudar. Até pq você precisaria trocar o target framework que está usando no seu projeto, então isso não parece fazer sentido. Fora isso, é impossível acontecer o que você comenta na pergunta porque a ordenação é numérica, ou você está testando com o bloco de código errado, ou falta informação na pergunta.

Comment: Minha dica pra você é: isole o código e teste com um conjunto de dados pré-definidos. Além disso, sempre deixe um caso de teste pronto na sua pergunta — principalmente um que esteja falhando, porque aí quem quiser te ajudar tem um ponto de partida.

Comment: @LINQ Eu achei que pudesse ser da atualização pois antes estava a funcionar. Vou adicionar mais código à pergunta e vou testar como você disse.

Comment: Sim, tranquilo. Esta é uma confusão normal mesmo, ainda mais que o problema começou a aparecer depois de atualizar. Mas faça isso, adicione mais detalhes que fica melhor de tentar te ajudar.

Comment: @LINQ já adicionei um teste e alterei a pergunta.

Comment: Eu vou escrever uma resposta. Veja bem, eu percebi que você já tem um certo tempo de site. Depois de responder eu vou editar sua pergunta e formatá-la e você usa esta pergunta como base de formatação para suas próximas perguntas, pode ser?

Comment: @LINQ certo, mas o que tem de errado com a minha pergunta?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93683/discussion-between-sofia-rodrigues-and-linq).

Comment: está ordenando strings em vez de numeros... os valores para ordenar ficam sempre entres os caracteres `_` e `.` ?

Comment: @vik certo, fica " _nome_ _0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente este código nunca funcionou antes, pelo menos não no caso de teste que foi citado na sua pergunta.

O que acontece no seu código é o seguinte.

1. **`GetFiles`** retorna uma lista de *strings* (aliás, seria bom ter citado isto na pergunta).

   Pela imagem, vi que a lista de strings seria algo como

   ```
   var tifffiles = new[] 
   { 
       "C:\\Qualquercoisa_v2\\anual_2009\\anual_2009_0", 
       "C:\\Qualquercoisa_v2\\anual_2009\\anual_2009_2", 
       "C:\\Qualquercoisa_v2\\anual_2009\\anual_2009_1", 
       "C:\\Qualquercoisa_v2\\anual_2009\\anual_2009_5", 
       "C:\\Qualquercoisa_v2\\anual_2009\\anual_2009_11", 
       "C:\\Qualquercoisa_v2\\anual_2009\\anual_2009_4", 
       "C:\\Qualquercoisa_v2\\anual_2009\\anual_2009_10",  
   };
   ```
2. Nesta lista de strings é chamado o método `OrderBy` com a seguinte função de ordenação

   ```
   new string(f.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray()
   ```

   Isso quer dizer que para cada elemento da coleção (essa do passo 1) será criada uma nova *string* contendo **apenas as letras** — porque apenas letras retornam `true` na chamada de `char.IsDigit`.

   Ou seja, os elementos usados na ordenação serão — note que isso não altera os elementos originais:

   ```
   CQualquercoisavanualanual
   CQualquercoisavanualanual
   CQualquercoisavanualanual
   CQualquercoisavanualanual
   CQualquercoisavanualanual
   CQualquercoisavanualanual
   CQualquercoisavanualanual
   ```

   Portanto, a coleção ordenada que é retornada mantém todos os elementos na mesma posição que estavam.
3. É feita uma chamada para o método `ThenBy`, usando a seguinte função de ordenação:

   ```
   int number; 
   if (int.TryParse(new string(f.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()), out number)) 
       return number; 
   return -1;
   ```

   O que esta função faz — **para cada elemento da coleção** — é o seguinte:

   1. **`f.Where(char.IsDigit)`** seleciona todos números da string original;
   2. **`new string`** cria uma nova string com os números selecionados;
   3. **`int.TryParse`** tenta converter a string gerada em um número inteiro de 32 bits (**ponto de atenção**) e retorna `true` se a conversão funcionar e `false` caso contrário; e
   4. **`return`** retorna o valor convertido se a conversão deu certo ou -1 caso contrário.

   Agora vamos tentar aplicar isso no primeiro elemento do *array* original

   ```
   C:\\Qualquercoisa_v2\\anual_2009\\anual_2009_0
   ```

   1. Selecionar todos os números: `2200920090`
   2. Criar uma string com estes números: `"2200920090"`
   3. Tentar converter para `int`: **Problema aqui**

   **[Veja o código de teste no repl.it](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/pt-so384133-tryparse)**

   Agora é só entender o que tá causando este erro =)

   O que acontece aí é que os números são maiores do que um inteiro de **32 bits**. Para este caso específico (e mais uns vários) você pode simplesmente trocar para um inteiro de 64 bits (`long`). Ou seja, alterar a segunda função de ordenação para

   ```
   long number; 
   if (long.TryParse(new string(f.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()), out number)) 
   ...
   ```

Meu conselho na verdade é rever este código e tentar reescrevê-lo.

Comment: LINQ resolvendo problemas nativos de sua própria natureza, impressionante.

Comment: Para além de uma excelente explicação sobre o problema e o código, uma boa resposta.

Comment: A melhor parte é a última frase :)

Answer (score 1):

A ideia aqui será criar um objecto do tipo anónimo para auxiliar a ordenação, com o nome do ficheiro e com o valor a ordenar... este exemplo tem em conta que o valor para ordenar fica sempre entre o ultimo caractere `_` e o `.`

```
    string[] files = new string[] {

        @"C:\Users\Utilizador\Pictures\revenche_2019_0.png",
        @"C:\Users\Utilizador\Pictures\revenche_2019_1.png",
        @"C:\Users\Utilizador\Pictures\revenche_2019_11.png",
        @"C:\Users\Utilizador\Pictures\revenche_2019_2.png",
        @"C:\Users\Utilizador\Pictures\revenche_2019_12.png",
        @"C:\Users\Utilizador\Pictures\revenche_2019_3.png"
    };

    var result = files.Select(f => new
    {
        file = f,
        index = int.Parse(string.Concat(f.Skip(f.LastIndexOf('_') + 1).TakeWhile(f2 => f2 != '.')))
    }).OrderBy(an => an.index)
    .Select(an => an.file)
    .ToList();

    result.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
```

Comment: Mas aí se misturar de dois anos diferentes já era, né.

Comment: A sua resposta funcionou como a de LINQ, a questão é que a sua está limitada a nomes com esse formato e a de LINQ dá para utilizar em vários casos. Apesar da sua resposta estar certa, a de LINQ funciona melhor para mim.

Comment: @LINQ, pois, no nome da pasta já tem o ano, não sei se poderá ter outros ficheiros... mas sua solução tambem tem esse problema do ano, imagine que o ficheiro 0 de 2009 trás o valor 2200920090, e o 10 de 2008 irá trazer 22009200810, este ultimo é maior que o primeiro....

Comment: @SofiaRodrigues o importante é resolver seu problema :)